# Take log values on multiple columns DataFrame

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, logging, machine-learning

I need to take log values of each element of a column in a DataFrame.Also i want to add the resulted column to the previous dataframe.

This is my dataframe

```
df1=pd.read_csv('doctors.csv',encoding='latin-1')
```

These are the columns

```
Index(['PatientID', 'Pregnancies', 'PlasmaGlucose', 'DiastolicBloodPressure',
       'TricepsThickness', 'SerumInsulin', 'BMI', 'DiabetesPedigree', 'Age',
       'Diabetic', 'Physician'],
      dtype='object')
```

I want to form a new column of logarithmic values for 'Age' column.

Comment: Can yo uadd data sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need [`numpy.log10`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log10.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age':[10,22,33,44,34,56,34]})
df['log'] = np.log10(df['Age'])
print (df)
   Age       log
0   10  1.000000
1   22  1.342423
2   33  1.518514
3   44  1.643453
4   34  1.531479
5   56  1.748188
6   34  1.531479
```